# Alternative to byte array property in Entity Framework Code First object class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I know that similar questions have been asked here many times but I believe this is a very specific case.

In a code first class I need a property to represent a very small image (the image must be stored in the DB). I have in the past defined a property like `public byte[] MyAutograph { get; set; }`. When this is migrated to the DB it creates a varbinary(max) as expected.

Code analysis puts up a squiggly stating that "**a property should not return an array**". I can ignore that but was curious if this should be ignored or if in the context of an entity framework object is there a better way to define a property to hold an image in a SQL database?

Comment: Make the variable private and create a method to return the array.

Comment: Code analysis doesn't know that this is an acceptable thing to have in an EF entity. Suppress the message and move on.

Comment: And if there's some other property type you want the entity to have, you can declare the Entity with a Value Conversion.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions, or you can use Table Splitting to avoid loading the image for use cases where it's not needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting

Comment: Alternatively you can use a string as storage type and use the Convert.ToBase64String and Convert.FromBase64String